# Doctrine doesn't update entity's field

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a simple entity:

```
<?php

namespace SomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\PostRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="Posts")
*/
class Post {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $ID;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="Title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
    */
    protected $Title;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="Text", type="text", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $Text;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="Picture", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
    */
    protected $Picture;

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->Title;
    }

    public function getID() {
        return $this->ID;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->Title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->Title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->Text;
    }

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->Text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPicture() {
        return $this->Picture;
    }

    public function setPicture($picture) {
        $this->Picture= $picture;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and I have a controller action:

```
public function editAction($ID, Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository("SomeBundle:Post")->find($ID);

    if (!$entity)
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("Unable to find post.");

    $form = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $this->validateData($form, $entity);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entity->setTitle('Title');
        $entity->setPicture('somefilepath');
        $em->flush();
    }
    ...
}
```

So, when I trigger editAction function, Title field is updated correctly, but not the Picture. Picture field is not even listed in update query in profiler:

```
UPDATE Posts SET Title = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. It appeared that entity's custom repository did not attach Picture field to the entity, therefore doctrine did not process the field during flushing.